# Replace Every Instance of '-' from a file

Tags: python, file

I have a file that contains information like the below:

```
1/1/2010
1-2-3-4
1
1/2/2010
1-5-6-7
111
etc.
```

I want to be able to write this to another file where every instance of `'-'` is replaced with `','`. I have tried using `str.split('-')` and realize I cannot write a list to a file after receiving this error
`TypeError: must be string or read-only character buffer, not list`
I have also tried using `str.replace('-', 'i')` but all this gives me is another error
`TypeError: replace() takes at least 2 arguments (1 given)`
Can anyone point me in the right direction?

I should also point out the reason I was attempting to use `str.split()` in the first place is because eventually this will all be put in a dictionary like so

```
{0:[['1/1/2010], ['1', '2', '3', '4'], ['1']], 1: [['1/2/2010'], ['1', '5', '6', '7'], ['111']], etc.}
```

Just an update...
I found an easy way to do this using Regular Expressions that was not mentioned.

```
>>> def test(filename):
import re
input_file = open(filename, 'r')
output_file = open('test.txt', "w")
for line in input_file:
    line = line.strip()
    line = re.sub('-', ',', line)
    output_file.write(line)
    output_file.write('\n')
input_file.close()
output_file.close()
```

Comment: Is this to be integrated in another program? Do you need to use python for this step? If not why not a shell command: cat file | tr "-" ","

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
def replaceAll(infilepath, outfilepath):
    infile = open(infilepath)
    outfile = open(outfilepath, 'w')
    for line in infile:
        outfile.write(line.replace('-', ','))
    infile.close()
    outfile.close()
```

EDIT: Here's a slightly more pythonic way of doing this:

```
def replaceAll(infilepath, outfilepath):
    with open(infilepath) as infile,  open(outfilepath, 'w') as outfile:
        for line in infile:
            outfile.write(line.replace('-', ','))
```

Comment: That works. Thanks for providing a little more than `replace('-', ',')`.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you use regex to parse your file if the format is this consistent, here is an example:

```
import os, re

data = """1/1/2010
1-2-3-4
1
1/2/2010
1-5-6-7
111"""

regex = re.compile(os.linesep.join([r'(\d{1,2}/\d{1,2}/\d{4})',
                                    r'(\d+-\d+-\d+-\d+)',
                                    r'(\d+)']))
groups = {}
n = 0
for match in regex.finditer(data):
    groups[n] = [[match.group(1)], match.group(2).split('-'), [match.group(3)]]
    n += 1

>>> groups
{0: [['1/1/2010'], ['1', '2', '3', '4'], ['1']], 1: [['1/2/2010'], ['1', '5', '6', '7'], ['111']]}
```

As for your question (how to replace hyphens with commas), assuming you have read your file into the string `data`, you can replace all hyphens with commas using the following line:

```
data = data.replace('-', ',')
```

You could also split the string on all `'-'` and then use `','.join()`, although using `str.replace()` is simpler:

```
data = ','.join(data.split('-'))
```

Comment: I tried the above with just a sample(9 lines) of my data and it returned `{}`.

Comment: If your lines have any trailing whitespace or the file has weird line endings this might not work, can you edit your question with the lines you tried it on?

Comment: I tried it exactly how you have it above, but when I type in groups it still gives me `{}`. Are you using 2.7.2?

Comment: Nope, still the same thing in 3.1.

Answer (score 0):

try using this

```
replace("-",",");
```

Comment: Maybe it's because I don't know enough Python but when I use try reading lines in a file with this it does not work. i.e. `line.replace("-", ",")` all it copied over to the file was the first line from the file it was reading.

Comment: Look at the very bottom of this page from the Python docs: http://docs.python.org/library/string.html

Comment: `replace` returns a new `str`. The one you invoke it on is unchanged. It's far from obvious and results in ugly code like `message = message.replace("-", ",")`. On another note, the semicolon at the end in this answer doesn't belong.

Comment: The accepted answer uses `replace("-", ",")`. Are you going to complain to that guy too? I realize my answer doesn't explain how to everything, but at the time I thought it was only the replacing he was struggling with, mostly since that's the only code he posted.

Answer (score 0):

I created a test file to show you. First, read it in:

```
>>> contents = open('test.txt', 'r').read()
>>> contents
'blah-blah\nsomething-\n'
```

Use the string replace method to replace occurrences of `-` with `,`:

```
>>> contents_replaced = contents.replace('-', ',')
>>> contents_replaced
'blah,blah\nsomething,\n'
```

Write it back out to a file and read it in to make sure it was updated:

```
>>> open('test2.txt', 'w').write(contents_replaced)
>>> open('test2.txt', 'r').read()
'blah,blah\nsomething,\n'
```